# Getting No table used error 1096

Tags: php, codeigniter

Designing an application in CI and came across this strange issue. 
Below is Modal

```
public function _get_datatables_query()
    {
        $sql = "select inv2.id,inv1.uniqueid,inv2.pastamount_due, c.name 
        FROM invoices as inv2 
        JOIN (SELECT max(id) as maxid, uniqueid from invoices GROUP by uniqueid)
        as inv1 on (inv2.id=inv1.maxid and inv2.uniqueid=inv1.uniqueid) 
        JOIN client as c ON inv2.uniqueid = c.uniqueid";

$query = $this->db->query($sql);
if($query !== false)
{
   return $query->result();
}

return NULL; //$query is false. Probably due to bad syntax in the query string

        $i = 0;
        // var_dump($this->column_search );

        foreach ($this->column_search as $item) // loop column 
        {  

            if($_POST['search']['value']) // if datatable send POST for search
            {

                if($i===0) // first loop
                {
                    $this->db->group_start(); // open bracket. query Where with OR clause better with bracket. because maybe can combine with other WHERE with AND.
                    $this->db->like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->db->or_like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
                }

                if(count($this->column_search) - 1 == $i) //last loop
                    $this->db->group_end(); //close bracket
            }
            $i++;
        }

        if(isset($_POST['order'])) // here order processing
        {
            $this->db->order_by($this->column_order[$_POST['order']['0']['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);
        } 
        else if(isset($this->order))
        {
            $order = $this->order;
            $this->db->order_by(key($order), $order[key($order)]);
        }
    }

    function get_datatables()
    {
        $this->_get_datatables_query();
        if($_POST['length'] != -1)
        $this->db->limit($_POST['length'], $_POST['start']);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Below is Controller
public function ajax_list()
    {

```
    $list = $this->client->get_datatables();

    $data = array();
    $no = $_POST['start'];


        foreach ($list as $client) {
        $no++;
        $row = array();
        $client=(array)$client;
        $row[] = isset($client['name'])?$client['name']:"---";
        $row[] = isset($client['city'])?$client['city']:"---";
        $row[] = isset($client['amount_due'])?"Rs.".$client['amount_due']:"Rs.00.00";
        $row[] = isset($client['lastdispatch'])?$client['lastdispatch']:"---";
        $row[] = isset($client['lastbill'])?$client['lastbill']:"--";
        $row[] = isset($client['lastpayment'])?$client['lastpayment']:"---";
    }

    $output = array(
                    "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
                    //"recordsTotal" => $this->person->count_all(),
                    //"recordsFiltered" => $this->person->count_filtered(),
                    "recordsTotal" => $this->client->count_all(),
                    "recordsFiltered" => $this->client->count_filtered(),
                    "data" => $data,
            );

    //output to json format
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

While compiling the application I am geeting error 1096: No table used. Select * limit 10. I am not sure where I am going wrong as instead of using get() I am returning the query result.Can someone please help !!!

Answer (score 0):

Remove those lines From function get_datatables():

```
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

You are inserting into the db, then you are running empty query with `get()`

Link For Help **[Here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#insert)**

Comment: Now I am getting Invalid argument error in controller for                foreach ($list as $client) {
        $no++;
        $row = array();

Comment: WHat is `$this->db`? What do you expect to be returned by `$this->client->get_datatables();`?